# Get my Visio 2013 template on the New page

Tags: visio

I've created a new template.  How do I get the template to show up when I want to create a new drawing.

I did a search on .vstx and found this folder.  I saved it here, but it still doesn't show up.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\Visio Content\1033

This template will be the base for many drawings and I would like to be able to select it quickly while in meetings.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In 2013 you need to go to Options/Advanced and scroll down to the bottom where it has a button for File Locations.  Add a folder for templates and then save the template to that folder.  Your template will show up in the New under Categories instead of Featured.

Answer (score 1):

- On the File menu, click Save As. In the Save as type list, click
  Template (*.vst). In the File name box, type a name for your
  template. Click the arrow next to Save, and make sure that Workspace
  is selected (checked). In the Save in list, select the folder in
  which you want to save the template.

**Tip** If you want the template to appear in the list that Visio displays when you click New on the File menu, save the template in the Solutions folder or one of its subfolders.

Note In Visio 2003, click the arrow next to Save, and make sure that Workspace is selected. In Visio 2007, click Save workspace on the Summary tab in the Properties window.
Click Save.

[Link for these steps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294245)

Answer (score 0):

Save your template as a Visio template (.vst file) in whatever location you want for your custom templates.  Then you have a choice.

1. As Matt616 says, you could go to Options/Advanced in Visio 2013, click on "File Locations" and then enter your location as the location for templates.  If you do this, then when you want to create a new drawing, your custom templates will appear under the Categories tab.  The trouble with this is that the Categories tab is already full of other stuff.
2. As a (possibly better) alternative, go to Options/Save in Visio 2013 and enter your location as "Default personal templates location".  If you do this, then when you want to creat a new drawing, there will be a new tab above the list of templates, called "Personal".  Click this and you will see just your custom templates and no other stuff.  Also, templates in this tab are pinnable (which doesn't seem to work in the "Categories" tab) and any templates that you pin will appear under "Featured" in future.